# Why does select ... for UPDATE locks inserts?

Tags: mysql, locks

I'm running a transaction which looks like below :

```
BEGIN()
SELECT * FROM mytable LIMIT 1
COMMIT()
```

The issue is that if I try to insert new data in `mytable` concurrently  it takes longer than usually so I assume the transaction locks `mytable` for inserts. Is that possible?

MySQL server engine is `InnoDB`, latest version

Comment: does MySQL really use `commit()` instead of `commit`?

Comment: Certainly, not only possible but essential. Otherwise the INSERT could insert something that would conflict with the UPDATE, such as a key value that the UPDATE would duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to the top of your query:

`SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED`

By default it allows the query to try and read data that is currently being inserted to the table, resulting in a deadlock.

With this flag, it will only set the values that are already in the table when you start running your query.

Comment: Is it possible to set this on that table only? It seems dangerous to change the isolation  on the whole database.

Comment: It's not going to change it on the database level, but on the ````TRANSACTION```` level, so it should be fine.

Comment: when I try to change it in a transaction I get this error ``Transaction isolation level can't be changed while a transaction is in progress``

Comment: @hey I have added a fiddle here - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0b5d4/1 - the script won't run, but this should be the syntax you are looking for. Can you try it like this?

Comment: Ok, now I understand. Shouldn't the transaction level apply to all the tables/database as I said?(given your syntax).  I understand it applies at the "transaction" level but we have many transactions on different tables  so ideally I hoped I could enable it on a specific transaction only not on all the transactions(aka the whole database). Btw the fiddle showed MSSQL. The question is tagged as MySQL, though I don't think it makes any difference.

Comment: "Without any SESSION or GLOBAL keyword, the statement sets the isolation level for the next (not started) transaction performed within the current session." This is what I've found in this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/set-transaction.html